# Not getting a correct address from Latitude & Longitude

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I want to get the true postal address from the Latitude & Longitude, however is not working well. Maybe I am note using the right APIs or etc.

For example I have the following code

```
           var location = CLLocation(latitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        print(location)

            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark
                street = String(pm.thoroughfare!)
                city = String(pm.locality!)
                state = String(pm.administrativeArea!)
                print(pm.locality)
                print(pm.administrativeArea)
                print(pm.thoroughfare)
                self.utility.setMyLocation(dName, longitude: long, latitude: lat, street: street, city: city, state: state)
                locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            }
            else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
```

However I am not getting the true address. For example let say if that long and lat address is

123 East Street

I get something like only East Street (with no number) or near by road.

What do I need to do inorder to get the real address?

Comment: Something to note is that depending on what service you are using, you will get different LAT/LON. The different LAT/LON are probably similar and geographically close to each other, but they may be different. Here is a question that shows this http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/160103/59301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what your looking for but its what i currently use to get a nice readable address. I also send these values to my Application delegate for referencing later if i need them. I don't have it written in Swift however just in Objective C. :/ But i think the key is `reverseGeocodeLocation`

```
#pragma mark - location Manager update and FUNCTIONS
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%s Failed with Error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"%s Update to Location: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, newLocation);
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        NSLog(@"Longitude: %@", longitude);
        NSLog(@"Latitude: %@", latitude);

        // Set current values to the AppDelegate for refrencing
        appDelegate.locationDetailLon = longitude;
        appDelegate.locationDetailLat = latitude;
    }

    // Stop Location Manager to save power
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Translating and getting the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
            NSLog(@"Address:\n%@", address);

            // Set current values to the AppDelegate for refrencing
            appDelegate.locationDetailState = placemark.administrativeArea;
            appDelegate.locationDetailCountry = placemark.country;
            appDelegate.locationDetailCity = placemark.locality;
            appDelegate.locationDetailPostCode = placemark.postalCode;


        } else {
            NSLog(@"%s ERROR: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
}
```